# Plotly.js modebar buttons navigating to current page

Tags: plotly, svelte, sveltekit, plotly.js

I'm using [Plotly.js](https://plotly.com/javascript/) on a [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) app, and I have this issue that if I have a plot on the page, any `<a>` tag with no `href` attribute will trigger a route change to the same route when clicked, which is causing problems and a broken UX.
Any clue?

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from "svelte";

    onMount(() => {
        var trace1 = {
            x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
            mode: 'markers',
            type: 'scatter'
            };

        var trace2 = {
            x: [2, 3, 4, 5],
            y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
            mode: 'lines',
            type: 'scatter'
            };

        var trace3 = {
            x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            y: [12, 9, 15, 12],
            mode: 'lines+markers',
            type: 'scatter'
            };

        var data = [trace1, trace2, trace3];

            Plotly.newPlot('example-plot', data);

    });
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js' crossorigin/>
</svelte:head>

<div id="container">
    <p>
        Test link: <a style="color: blue; cursor: pointer;">click here</a>
    </p>

    <!-- Plots go in blank <div> elements. 
        You can size them in the plot layout,
        or give the div a size as shown here.
    -->
    <div id="example-plot" style="width:900px; height:500px; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a bug. You might be able to prevent it by adding the [`data-sveltekit-reload`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options#data-sveltekit-reload) attribute to all the `a` elements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't solve the problem